# Domain model or base type in find method?

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

While implementing a find (or search) method in a repository class, is is better to accept a domain model or is it better to implement specific find methods?

For example we have a `Person` class with the attributes `name`, `id`.

In the repository we could have a `find` method that accepts a person as a parameter. That method will use the given model to search for an existing person.

The other approach is to implement a find method per attribute (`find_by_name`, `find_by_id`).

Since I will be implementing this in Python I could also implement a method accepting keywords. This will resemble the accept-a-model approach: `find(name='harry')`

As a side question, when the find method concerns an indexed value (`id`), is it better to use `get_by_id()` (which implies indexes) or `find_by_id()` (which is more abstract).

Comment: Why do you need to query for a `Person` if you already have that `Person` and can give it as an argument to the repository query function?

Comment: @AlexanderLanger The given `Person` instance is partial. For example only the `id` attribute may be set in the partial instance, the result will be a separate `Person` instance with both `name` and `id` set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use findBy(attribute) is preferrable in semantics and more meaningfule if there is not many specific query requirements.

```
 personRepository.find_by_name(name); //is easy to read
 personRepository.find_by_age(age); //
 personRepository.find(person); //this one is at odds and confused
```

But if there are too many specific query methods on the repository, it's also a pain. In this case, you need a criteria. Pretty much the same way you use your find_by_person now, but more natural in semantics.

```
 criteria.nameEq = 'hippoom';
 personRepository.findBy(criteria);

 criteria.worksFor = 'XXX company';
 criteria.ageGt = 25
 personRepository.findBy(criteria);
```

Comment: Abstracting query syntax in a criteria object sound like a solid design. The need for these criteria however is explained in the answer by @StevePuder. If only I could accept both answers.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would implement specific find methods. A repository is a collection-like abstraction of the persistence mechanism and its interface *should be written in the semantics of your domain*.

Although queries like `find_by_name` or `find_by_id` are valid, very often one would need queries of the type `find_vip_persons` which could be a combination of several properties of the `Person` aggregate root (e.g. `salary > 10000 & age > 21`). Especially in cases like these I would avoid a generic query method, since the domain logic (i.e. what makes a person a VIP) could easily become scattered everywhere in your code base.

Although I'm not very familiar with Pythons keyword arguments and could be wrong here, I would assume that the 'accept-a-model approach' you're considering doesn't allow for more complex conditions like the VIP example from above anyway (i.e. comparison operators).

If you want use a generic repository interface and reuse queries at different locations in the domain, then you should have a look at the '[Specification Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf)'.

Regarding your 'Find vs. Get' question I'd say it doesn't really matter. I would probably use 'Query' instead, but that's just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Very nice example pointing out the complex queries, I totally forgot about those. Unfortunately Python's keyword arguments doesn't support othet operators, this is not what it was intended for at all. I do think I have to go for the other answer because of the critera approach. Good answer though.